What is the meaning of $E[V|Sell] = \sum_{V_i=V_{min}}^{V_i=V_{max}}V_iPr[V=V_i|Sell]$.
$E[V|Sell] = \sum_{V_i=V_{min}}^{V_i=V_{max}}V_iPr[V=V_i|Sell]$.
I am new to probability, so detailed explanation would really help.
Also what is $Pr[V = V_i|Sell]$ in this context?

Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Are you in the right class? It seems it might be expected you’re comfortable with conditional probability.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Random_variables_with_finitely_many_outcomes and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditioning_on_an_event .

This is the law of total probability.

Thank you everyone for the answers..Let me go back and digest this information. And will come back if I have a follow up question.

Here we assume $V$ is a random variable that takes values in some integer set $\{V_{min}, ..., V_{max}\}$, where $V_{min}$ and $V_{max}$ are some given (nonrandom) integers. Then the expectation of $V$ is given by the formula
$$ E[V] = \sum_{v=V_{min}}^{V_{max}} v P[V=v]$$
where $P[V=v]$ is the Probability Mass Function (PMF) of random variable $V$.
If $Sell$ is some event with $P[Sell]>0$, then we compute the conditional expectation of $V$ given $Sell$ by using the conditional PMF of $V$ given $Sell$ (note the similarity to the formula for $E[V]$):
$$ E[V|Sell] = \sum_{v=V_{min}}^{V_{max}} v P[V=v|Sell]$$

Here $v$ is just a dummy index used in the summation. Instead of calling the dummy index $v$, you can call it $w$ or $j$ or anything you want. The formula stated in your question uses the dummy index $V_i$ which is valid, but I find that just using $v$ is simpler.
Note that $\{V=v\}$ is an event, $\{Sell\}$ is an event, so the conditional probability $P[V=v|Sell]$ is defined by the standard formula for conditional probability $P[A|B]$ for two events $A,B$.

Exercise: Suppose $V \in \{3, 4, 5, 6\}$ with $P[V=v]=1/4$ for $v \in \{3,4,5,6\}$. Define the event $Sell=\{V\geq 5\}$.
a) Compute $E[V]$.
b) Compute $P[Sell]$.
c) Compute $P[V=3|Sell], P[V=4|Sell], P[V=5|Sell], P[V=6|Sell]$.
d) Compute $E[V|Sell]$.

If you appreciated this answer, you can give your response to the exercises I provided. It should just take a few minutes and it helps understand and affirm the abstract concepts given in my answer.

E[V] = 3/4 + 4/4 + 5/4 + 6/4 = 18/4 or 4.5
P[Sell] = 1/4 + 1/4 = 2/4 or 0.5
P[V=3|Sell] = P[V=3 and Sell) /P[Sell] = 0
P[V=4|Sell] = P[V=4 and Sell) /P[Sell] = 0
P[V=5|Sell] = P[V=5 and Sell) /P[Sell] = 1/2
P[V=6|Sell] = P[V=6 and Sell) /P[Sell] = 1/2

how to calculate E[V|Sell]?? plz advise @Michael

The summation formulas are given above.  You used the values ${3,4,5,6}$ and $(1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4)$ to calculate $E[V]=\sum_{v=3}^{6}vP[V=v]$. Now you can use the values ${3,4,5,6}$ and $(0,0,1/2,1/2)$ to calculate $E[V|Sell]=\sum_{v=3}^6vP[V=v|Sell]$.
